# How to stop a parallel loop when an error has been raised

Tags: r, error-handling, parallel-processing, future

I create parallel loops using the `future` package. Sometime the expression called raise an error. In that cases the whole process is ran (takes a long time) and the function fails only at the end when the futures are evaluated.

Instead the function should fail when an error is raised. Especially if the error is raised at the beginning of the process. For example this code will fail only after 100 iterations but it is actually likely to fail before the 10th one.

```
g = function()
{
  future::plan(future::multiprocess, workers = 4)

  x = vector("list", 100)
  for(i in 1:100)
  {
    x[[i]] = future::future(
    {
        u = runif(1, 0, 100)
        if (u > 80) 
          stop("Error")
        return(u)
    })

    cat(sprintf("\rProgress: %g%%", i, file = stderr()))
  }

  return(future::values(x))
}
```

How to manage error handling with `future`?

Comment: maybe this discussion can help https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/154

Comment: I already read this thread but I was not able to figure out if/how it can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is set `earlySignal = TRUE` as in:

```
   g = function()
{
  future::plan(future::multiprocess, earlySignal = TRUE, workers = 4)

  x = vector("list", 100)
  for(i in 1:100)
  {
    x[[i]] = future::future(
      {
        u = runif(1, 0, 100)
        if (u > 80) 
          stop("Error")
        return(u)
      })

    cat(sprintf("\rProgress: %g%%", i, file = stderr()))
  }

  return(future::values(x))
}

g()
```

Comment: Author of future here. I'm surprised that `future::plan(future::multiprocess(earlySignal = TRUE), workers = 4)` actually works. Please use future::plan(future::multiprocess, earlySignal = TRUE, workers = 4)` instead (we're basically doing ["currying"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) on `future::multiprocess`)

Comment: could please edit code in your answer accordingly - because there is great risk that your answer will break in a future release of the package - I've suggested an edit myself, but it looks like it's being down voted (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19417188)

Comment: @henrikb sure no problem.  Thanks for your work! It is a very important package!